# IfElse with OR operator

Tags: r

Trying to collapse several variables into dichotomous variables. I want to assign new values based on conditional values in the original variable using the OR operator "|"

dataframe c has "reason" column with values: ("answered", "could not talk", "called_back", "unanswered", "voicemail")

```
# Collapse several responses into one value
c$answered <- if(c$reason == "answered"  | 
                     "couldNotTalk" |
                     "called_back") 
                    {c$answer == "answered"}
              else {c$unanswer == "not answered"}
```

This isn't working, but the following is (even though it is not efficient):

```
"Answered" -> c$answer[c$reason == "answered"] 
"Answered" -> c$answer[c$reason == "couldNotTalk"]
"Answered" -> c$answer[c$reason == "called_back"]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case, rather than doing a bunch of or's, you can use `%in%`, for examples

```
c$reason %in% c("answered", "couldNotTalk", "called_back")
```

Then to use this with a vector of values, rather than using `if`, you can use the vectorized version called `ifelse()`.

```
c$answered <-  ifelse(
  c$reason %in% c("answered", "couldNotTalk", "called_back"),
  "answered",
  "not answered"
)
```

or course you could also

Comment: Thanks. The second one was what I was trying to do, so is perfect.